# Convergence of a product

Tags: sequences-and-series, products

I want to show the following product converges for $x<e$ and diverges for $x \ge e$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(x-\frac{xi}{n}\right).$$

To do this, I would need to show that the natural log of the product converges or diverges, i.e.:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\ln{\left(x-\frac{xi}{n}\right)}$$
converges or diverges. How would I show this?

Comment: Be careful - you're not trying to show that a single infinite product converges or diverges. Rather, you have a sequence of expressions (given by related but different finite products), and you're trying to prove that the sequence converges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second expression equals
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg( n \bigg( \ln x + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac1n \ln\Big( 1-\frac in \Big) \bigg) \bigg).
$$
The sum is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 \ln(1-x)\,dx =-1$. This isn't the end of the proof, because it's being multiplied by $n$ inside the limit, but it should suggest a way to finish off the proof.

Comment: But $\int_{0}^{1} \ln{(1-x)}dx=-1/(1-x)|_{0}^{1}=1/0+1/1$, right?

Comment: Nope, you took the derivative, not the anti-derivative.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing, ha. I'll look into that sum being a Riemann sum, I've never seen that one before.